# Inheriting from generic WeakEventManager creates error

Tags: generics

I want to make `WeakEventCollectionWeaver` to bind multiple `ObservableCollection`s together.

I inherit it like this:

```
public class WeakEventCollectionWeaver<T> : 
  WeakEventManager<ObservableCollection<T>, 
  NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> { }
```

but I get an error:

> CS1729 `WeakEventManager<ObservableCollection<T>,
>   NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>` does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 0 arguments

I looked it up and I believe I do not have to implement any constructor. So why this error is even there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to inherit that class. It has a private constructor (hence no default constructor), so descendant classes cannot call it.

Take a look at the source of the class here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManagerT.cs,a795c952f2e86713

Comment: So i cant inherit it in anyway? Isnt there a pattern for this?

Comment: Basic object orientation dictates that it is not (and should not be) possible and I'm almost positive that there are no patterns for inheriting a class with private constructor.

Comment: So the only option is a wrapper?

Comment: Since the constructor is private, you cannot create instances even yourself, so there is nothing to wrap.

Comment: but I did create an instance(or called static members). and why wouldn't I create a constructor of my own on the derived class? I do not ignore OOP principles by doing that, right?

Comment: You might have called static members, but you could definitely not create an instance. If you want, you can create a wrapper around the static method calls, but they will call the 'same instances'  of the static methods (i.e. if you wrap the AddHandle method with YourClass.Add, and create two instances of YourClass, the add method will call the the same AddHandle in both).

Comment: And regarding OO principles and ctor: It is the responsibility of the ctor to initialize an object of any type. If you have type A, then it is the responsibility of type A ctor to initialize objects of type A. If you have type B deriving from type A, then it is the responsibility of type B ctor to initialize objects of type B. But type B is partially A, so the 'A part' must be initialized as well, and that is the responsibility of type A ctor. So type B ctor must call type A ctor, but if type A ctor is private, this cannot be done. That's why inheritance doesn't work in this case.